# why can't it show books that has more than 2 authors?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am supposed to find the **ISBN**, **title of book**, and **publisher** of books that have **at least two authors** and at **most three authors**.

what I did :

```
db.Subject.aggregate([
    {"$match": {$and: [{"subject.book.author.3": {$exists: false}},
                           {"subject.book.author.1": {$exists: true}}]}},
        {"$project": {"subject.book.ISBN": 1,"subject.book.bookTitle": 1,"subject.book.publisher": 1}}
]).pretty();
```

the result that I have gotten only showed the books with 2 authors but it does not show the books with 3 authors.
How do I go about showing both 2 AND 3 authors?

An example of my script :

```
db.Subject.insert(
{
"_id":ObjectId(),
"subject": {
        "subCode":"CSCI103",
        "subTitle":"Algorithm and Problem Solving",
        "credit":3,
        "type":"Core",
        "assessments": [
                { "assessNum": 1,
                  "weight":10,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Problem Solving and Invariant" },
                { "assessNum": 2,
                  "weight":10,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 1 - Sorting and Seaarching, Linked Lists, and Stack and Queues" },
                { "assessNum": 3,
                  "weight":10,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 2 - Recursion, Trees, and Algorithmic Strategies" },
                { "assessNum": 4,
                  "weight":10,
                  "assessType":"Test/Quiz",
                  "description":"Closed-book Class Test" },
                { "assessNum": 5,
                  "weight":60,
                  "assessType":"Examination",
                  "description": "Closed-book Final Examination" }
            ],
        "book": [
                { "ISBN":"13:978-0-13-231681-1",
                  "bookType":"textbook",
                  "bookTitle":"Introduction to the Design and Analysis of Algorithms",
                  "edition":3,
                  "yearPub":2012,
                  "publisher":"Pearson",
                  "author": [ "Anany Levitin" ] },
                { "ISBN":"13:978-0-13-231681-1",
                  "bookType":"reference",
                  "edition":3,
                  "yearPub":2005,
                  "publisher":"Pearson",
                  "author": [ "B A Forouzan", "D S Malik", "M K Sen Thomson" ] }

            ]
        }
}
)

db.Subject.insert(
{
"_id":ObjectId(),
"subject": {
        "subCode":"CSCI114",
        "subTitle":"Procedural Programming",
        "credit":3,
        "type":"Core",
        "assessments": [
                { "assessNum": 1,
                  "weight":5,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 1 - Basic Concepts: Sequential Designs" },
                { "assignNum": 2,
                  "weight":5,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 2 - Control structures: Selection Designs" },
                { "assessNum": 3,
                  "weight":5,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 3 - Repetition Designs and Functions I" },
                { "assessNum": 4,
                  "weight":15,
                  "assessType":"Test/Quiz",
                  "description":"Closed-book Class Test" },
                { "assessNum": 5,
                  "weight": 10,
                  "assessType":"Test/Quiz",
                  "description":"Laboratory Test" },
                { "assessNum": 6,
                  "weight": 10,
                  "assessType":"Test/Quiz",
                  "description": "Closed-book Class Test" },
                { "assessNum": 7,
                  "weight":50,
                  "assessType":"Examination",
                  "description": "Closed-book Final Examination" }
            ],
        "book": [
                { "ISBN":"13:978-1-133-52635-3",
                  "bookType":"reference",
                  "bookTitle":"C++ Programming - Program design including data structure",
                  "edition":6,
                  "yearPub":2013,
                  "publisher":"CENGAGE Learning",
                  "author": [ "Malik D S" ] },
                { "ISBN":"13:978-0-273-75983-6",
                  "bookType":"reference",
                    "bookTitle":"Starting Out With C++: From Control Structures through Objects",
                  "edition":7,
                  "yearPub":2012,
                  "publisher":"Addison-Wesley",
                  "author": [ "Tony Gaddis" ] },

            ]
        }
}
)

db.Subject.insert(
{
"_id":ObjectId(),
"subject": {
        "subCode":"CSCI124",
        "subTitle":"Applied Programming",
        "credit":3,
        "type":"Core",
        "prerequisite": ["csci114"],
        "assessments": [
                { "assessNum": 1,
                  "weight":12,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 1 - Application on binary file processing" },
                { "assignNum": 2,
                  "weight":12,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 2 - Application on pointers" },
                { "assessNum": 3,
                  "weight":12,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 3 - Application on classes and objects and dynamic data structures" },
                { "assessNum": 4,
                  "weight":14,
                  "assessType":"Laboratory",
                  "description":"Laboraory/Implementation Tasks" },
                { "assessNum": 5,
                  "weight": 50,
                  "assessType":"Examination",
                  "description":"Closed-book Final Examination" }
            ],
        "book": [
                { "ISBN":"10:1-4390-4023-0",
                  "bookType":"textbook",
                  "bookTitle":"Data Structures Using C++",
                  "edition":2,
                  "yearPub":2010,
                  "publisher":"CENGAGE Learning",
                  "author": [ "Malik D S" ] },
                { "ISBN":"13:978-1-133-52635-3",
                  "bookType":"reference",
                    "bookTitle":"C++ Programming - Program design including data structure",
                  "edition":6,
                  "yearPub":2013,
                  "publisher":"CENGAGE Learning",
                  "author": [ "Malik D S" ] },
                { "ISBN":"13:978-0-273-75983-6",
                  "bookType":"reference",
                    "bookTitle":"Starting Out With C++: From Control Structures through Objects",
                  "edition":7,
                  "yearPub":2012,
                  "publisher":"Addison-Wesley",
                  "author": [ "Tony Gaddis" ] }
            ]
        }
}
)

db.Subject.insert(
{ 
    "_id":ObjectId(),
    "subject":{ 
        "subCode":"CSCI235",
        "subTitle":"Database Systems",
        "credit":3,
        "type":"Core",
        "prerequisite": ["csci124","csci103"],
        "assessments": [
                { "assessNum": 1,
                  "weight":10,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 1 - Normalization and Indexing" },
                { "assignNum": 2,
                  "weight":10,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 2 - PL/SQL programming and Concurrency Control" },
                { "assessNum": 3,
                  "weight":10,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 3 - JSON/BSON and MongoDB" },
                { "assessNum": 4,
                  "weight":10,
                  "assessType":"Laboratory",
                  "description":"Laboraory/Implementation Tasks" },
                { "assessNum": 5,
                  "weight": 60,
                  "assessType":"Examination",
                  "description":"Closed-book Final Examination" }
            ],
        "book": [
                { "ISBN":"13:978-0-136-08620-8",
                  "bookType":"textbook",
                  "bookTitle":"Fundamentals of Database Systems",
                  "edition":6,
                  "yearPub":2010,
                  "publisher":"Addison-Wesley",
                  "author": [ "Ramez Elmasri", "Shamkant B Navathe" ] },
                { "ISBN":"0-07-246563-8",
                  "bookType":"reference",
                    "bookTitle":"Database Management Systems",
                  "edition":3,
                  "yearPub":2003,
                  "publisher":"McGraw-Hill",
                  "author": [ "Raghur Ramakrishnan", "Johannes Gehrke" ] } ]
  }
}
)

db.Subject.insert(
{ 
    "_id":ObjectId(),
    "subject":{ 
        "subCode":"CSCI203",
        "subTitle":"Algorithm and Data Structures",
        "credit":3,
        "type":"Core",
        "prerequisite": ["csci103"],
        "assessments": [
                { "assessNum": 1,
                  "weight":10,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 1 - Mathematic Concepts and Algorithm Complexity" },
                { "assignNum": 2,
                  "weight":15,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 2 - Linear and Non-linear Data Structure" },
                { "assessNum": 3,
                  "weight":15,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 3 - Greedy Algorithm and Branch-and-Bound" },
                { "assessNum": 4,
                  "weight": 60,
                  "assessType":"Examination",
                  "description":"Closed-book Final Examination" }
            ],
        "book": [
                { "ISBN":"13:978-0-13-231681-1",
                  "bookType":"textbook",
                  "bookTitle":"Introduction to the Design and Analysis of Algorithms",
                  "edition":3,
                  "yearPub":2012,
                  "publisher":"Pearson",
                  "author": [ "Levitin" ] },
                { "ISBN":"978-0-262-53305-8",
                  "bookType":"reference",
                    "bookTitle":"Introduction to Algorithms",
                  "edition":3,
                  "yearPub":2013,
                  "publisher":"The MIT Press",
                  "author": [ "Thomas H Cormen", "Charles E Leiserson", "Ronald L Riverst", "Clifford Stein" ] } ]
  }
}
)

db.Subject.insert(
{ 
    "_id":ObjectId(),
    "subject":{ 
        "subCode":"IACT201",
        "subTitle":"Professional Practice and Ethics",
        "credit":3,
        "type":"Elective",
        "assessments": [
                { "assessNum": 1,
                  "weight":35,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 1 - Ethical Dilemma Case Study" },
                { "assignNum": 2,
                  "weight":25,
                  "assessType":"Presentation",
                  "description":"Presentation of Case Study" },
                { "assessNum": 3,
                  "weight": 40,
                  "assessType":"Examination",
                  "description":"Closed-book Final Examination" }
            ]
  }
}
)

db.Subject.insert(
{ 
    "_id":ObjectId(),
    "subject":{ 
        "subCode":"CSCI321",
        "subTitle":"Final Year Project",
        "credit":6,
        "type":"Core",
        "assessments": [
                { "assessNum": 1,
                  "weight":30,
                  "assessType":"Presentation",
                  "description":"Prototype demonstration" },
                { "assignNum": 2,
                  "weight":70,
                  "assessType":"Implementation and Presentation",
                  "description":"Final product Presentation and assessment of product implementation by panel of project supervisors" }
            ]
  }
}
)
```

Comment: First document, there are 2 books. One has 1 author, other has 3 authors. Do you want to output this document without the first book, or just turn off this document?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$subject.book"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "subject.book.ISBN": 1,
      "subject.book.bookTitle": 1,
      "subject.book.publisher": 1,
      size_of_name: {
        $size: "$subject.book.author"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "size_of_name": {
        $gte: 2,
        $lte: 4
      }
    }
  }
])
```

try this code..

Comment: Hi this doesnt return anything

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/d8REuSUTzPZ
check this

Comment: after i pasted all my database script it says
invalid configuration:

must be an array of documents like '[ {_id: 1}, {_id: 2} ]'

or

must match 'db = { collection: [ {_id: 1}, {_id: 2} ] }'

Comment: I have updated the post and added my full database in. i don't have any idea what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$subject.book"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "subject.book.author.1": {
        $exists: true
      },
      "subject.book.author.3": {
        $exists: false
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "subject.book.ISBN": 1,
      "subject.book.bookTitle": 1,
      "subject.book.publisher": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X129PRIz9cI)